# Html : trying juxtapose a navigation block to an svg image

Tags: html, css

I would create this thing one my website ( it's photoshopped picture )
composed by at the left, a svg picture of a book and at the right, a "navigation block". The navigation block is list of links that redirect to other page but it finish.
 [image]

Unfortenately, I got this right now with my code :
[image]
which is :

```html
    <div id="custom-bg">
        <div id="alpha-layer">
            <div id="top-section">
                <div id="book">
                    <img src="img/book.svg" width="100">
                </div>
                <!-- nav -->
                <nav class="nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <!--<li class="nav-button">
                        <a href="index.html">Index</a>
                            </li>-->
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="ada bio.html">Biographie</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="site.html">Programme Ada</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="babbage.html"> La machine de Babbage</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="#">Exemple de progamme Ada</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="bibliographie.html">Bibliographie</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and my css file :

```css
html,

body {
    background-image: url("../img/bg32.svg");
    padding : 0px ;
    margin: 0px;
}

div#custom-bg {
    background-image: url("../img/bg32.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position : center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

div#alpha-layer {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    padding : 25px;
}

div#top-section {
    display: inline-block;
}


nav.nav-bar ul li.nav-button {
    list-style-type: none;
}

nav.nav-bar ul li.nav-button a {
    background-color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    color : white;
    display: block;

    padding: 10px;
    width: 250px;
}

nav.nav-bar ul li.nav-button a:hover {
    background-color: darkgrey;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.5s all;
    color : white;

    padding: 10px;
}

div#book {
    vertical-align: top;
}
div.nav-bar {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

What should I add/change to get this result ?

Comment: I think you need to play with `position: absolute` for your image and change it's position to go where you want on your webpage. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Comment: I go searching how potion absolute work !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `display:inline-block` to the two divs next to each other (`#book` and `.nav-bar`):

```
.nav-bar, #book {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**Explanation:** By default, `div` elements have a display of `block`, meaning that they will always render on a "new line", and anything after them will also be rendered below them. By setting display to `inline-block`, we are removing this effect, while still preserving the div's width and height (unlike `inline` for example).

Below is a working snippet:

```css
html,

body {
    background-image: url("../img/bg32.svg");
    padding : 0px ;
    margin: 0px;
}

div#custom-bg {
    background-image: url("../img/bg32.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position : center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    padding-left: 2%;
    padding-right: 2%;
    padding-bottom: 0%;
    padding-top: 0%;
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

div#alpha-layer {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.25);
    padding : 25px;
}

div#top-section {
    display: inline-block;
}


nav.nav-bar ul li.nav-button {
    list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-bar, #book {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="custom-bg">
        <div id="alpha-layer">
            <div id="top-section">
                <div id="book">
                    <img src="img/book.svg" width="100">
                </div>
                <!-- nav -->
                <nav class="nav-bar">
                    <ul>
                        <!--<li class="nav-button">
                        <a href="index.html">Index</a>
                            </li>-->
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="ada bio.html">Biographie</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="site.html">Programme Ada</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="babbage.html"> La machine de Babbage</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="#">Exemple de progamme Ada</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-button">
                                <a href="bibliographie.html">Bibliographie</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: I got something really interessing ! If I ajust the svg size it's might be perfect ! :D

Comment: @Edhyjox Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking this post as answer. Have a good day!